# Agregar dependencias de 64 bits a proyecto de Android Studio

Tags: android, unity, google-play

En el desarrollo de un proyecto de Android Studio, al generar el APK y posteriormente subirlo a la Tienda de Google, nos despliega el siguiente comentario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya desde build.gradle he agregado la línea

```
ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
```

bajo el nodo

```
defaultConfig{}
```

Pero las librerías aún no aparecen dentro de la carpeta jniLibs. He investigado en los portales de Google acerca de como agregar estas dependencias, algo que aún no me queda claro, algún comentario al respecto de como proceder con esto?

Gracias!!!!

Comment: Tu proyecto usa libraries de terceros, cuales son? regularmente este es el problema.

Comment: El proyecto se genera en base a una versión de Unity 4.7.2f1, la cual no se puede modificar.

Comment: Sería de ayuda que publicaras que dependencias tienes definidas en tu archivo build.gradle @Gary

Comment: El siguiente enlace contiene lo que necesitas <https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html>